# Create a 2d Array for a maze game with Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, class, matrix, kotlin

So i have a Class called Cell and i want to create a matrix of objects Cell but im stuck and lost, this is what i got so far and its not working

How do i do this the right way? thanks

```
class GameView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : 
View(context, attrs) {

private val COLS:Int = 7
private val ROWS: Int = 10


fun createMaze(){

    //this gives me an error Type inference failed. Expected type 
    //mismatch: 
    //required:
    //Array<Array<Cell>>
    //found:
    //Array<IntArray>

    var cells: Array<Array<Cell>>  = Array(COLS, {IntArray(ROWS)})

    for(x in 0..COLS){
        for(y in 0..ROWS){
            cells[x][y] = Cell(x,y)
        }
    }

}

}

class Cell(var col:Int, var row: Int){
    var topWall = true
    var leftWall = true
    var bottomWall = true
    var rightWall = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your cells type as `Array<Array<Cell>>`, but initialized as `Array<IntArry>`

I think there is just a small change:

```
   class Cell(var col:Int=0, var row: Int=0){
        var topWall = true
        var leftWall = true
        var bottomWall = true
        var rightWall = true

    }
   var cells: Array<Array<Cell>>  = Array(COLS, {Array<Cell>(ROWS, {Cell()})})
```